# Unable to resolve IE rendering issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

First site i've built that get's this borked in IE9-older. Compatibility mode not helping. My employer shop is all mac, and the few PCs I tested on are rendering fine, but the client is running IE9, and it's not loading right. I tried on an old PC in the shipping dept running IE6 & similar borked result.

Been trying for hours to fix this site before it goes live on customer's domain. Staged at: http://hjshopper.com/littfin.temp/index.php

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it as i'm at a loss.

[UPDATE] So I've figured out most of the issues. Basically i'm a newb who was using html5 tags(header, section, etc) that old IE didn't like(so obvious now). Changing them to div with classes etc solved 90% of the problems.  No i just have to figure out the IE Z-index bug that is preventing the drop menu from showing on top of the main content.

Comment: What specifically is breaking? I tried loading it in IE11 and it looked fine.

Answer (score 0):

what about targeting just IE with a extra css, that is the better way around

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all_ie_sucks.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

and for IE 8 and 9

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="get_real_browser.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

this will do the trick..

and since you also need something for really old browser such IE this will do::

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-really.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But note that will be only for IE 6, if you want to target all browsers above IE6 this is the one you may want

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-rest-old-stuff.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

but i would create one for each of them, since they all render stuff differently..

Comment: So I'm trying this on the index.php: <!--[if lte IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->  But it doesn't seem to be reading it on an old ie6 computer in the shipping dept.

Answer (score 0):

I opened your site in IE 9 (on windows 7) and it worked fine but if I turn on the "Compatibility mode" of the browser the site renders wrong. In that case you have 2 options:
- Tell the users to disable the compatibily mode.
- Add this tag to your site head: . It forces the browser to use the latest rendering engine that is available despite what the user configures (maybe selecting standards to IE 8 or 7, or enabling the compatibility mode). Hope that helps.